# Why my Ionic App is receiving a forced "dark mode" on Android?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

My Ionic 4 app is getting a forced Dark Mode on Android 10+

I removed it on purpose from `theme/variable.scss` and it still has dark mode applied.
As my app doesn't implement anny dark style, all my texts are blank.

This is my variable.scss file:

1st try:

```
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {/* commented everything here*/}
```

2nd try:

```
@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {/* commented everything here*/}
```

3rd try:

```
just removed this part.....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **index.html**, remove 'dark' from `<meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark" />`

In **variables.css**, remove completely `@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) { body { . . . } }` section.

Further Info: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/24771

Comment: I'll try that. Since then I have simply let the app with the "error". Thx :D